# Python ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am parsing dates from a Dataframe where the data comes from a CSV file. I get the said error. I am sure the format is correct.

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime
    import csv
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    headers = ['Sensor Value','Date','Time']
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\DataLog.CSV',names=headers)
    print (df)

    df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
    x = df['Date']
    y = df['Sensor Value']

    # plot
    plt.plot(x,y)
    # beautify the x-labels
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

    plt.show()
```

My DataFrame:

```
0    Sensor Value         Date           Time
1               2   2017/02/17   19:06:17.188
2              72   2017/02/17   19:06:22.360
3              72   2017/02/17   19:06:27.348
```

Console Error:

```
   new_values = map_f(values, arg)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1207, in pandas.lib.map_infer     (pandas\lib.c:66124)
  File "C:/Users/Lala Rushan/PycharmProjects/newgraph/newgraph.py", line 10, in <lambda>
  df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
  File "C:\Users\Lala    Rushan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
  tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\Lala   Rushan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
  (data_string, format))
 ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

CSV Input:

```
    Sensor Value    Date    Time
2    2017/02/17  19:06:17.188
72   2017/02/17  19:06:22.360
72   2017/02/17  19:06:27.348
72   2017/02/17  19:06:32.482
74   2017/02/17  19:06:37.515
70   2017/02/17  19:06:42.580
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to do it this way, try `df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\DataLog.CSV',names=headers, parse_dates=['Date'])`

Comment: Are date and time seperate columns in your CSV? Please show some lines of the CSV input.

Comment: I tried it this way also and it gives me this error: **ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'**.

Comment: Additionally your `Date` string only has date fields, so you wanted `'%Y/%M/%D'` for the format field

Comment: You don't need the `map` code

Comment: can you provide a modified code for what you are saying? i am very new to python.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for parse problematic values to `NaN`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
```

For check problematic rows:

```
print (df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
```

But if need read columns `date` and time to `datetime` use parameter `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""
2,2017/02/17,19:06:17.188
72,2017/02/17,19:06:22.360
72,2017/02/17,19:06:27.348
72,2017/02/17,19:06:32.482
74,2017/02/17,19:06:37.515
70,2017/02/17,19:06:42.580"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'C:/Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\DataLog.CSV'
headers = ['Sensor Value','Date','Time']
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), names=headers, parse_dates={'Datetime':['Date','Time']})
print (df)
                 Datetime  Sensor Value
0 2017-02-17 19:06:17.188             2
1 2017-02-17 19:06:22.360            72
2 2017-02-17 19:06:27.348            72
3 2017-02-17 19:06:32.482            72
4 2017-02-17 19:06:37.515            74
5 2017-02-17 19:06:42.580            70

print (df.dtypes)
Datetime        datetime64[ns]
Sensor Value             int64
dtype: object
```

---

First solution combined with second, where in last row is `30.2.2017` what does not exist:

```
temp=u"""
2,2017/02/17,19:06:17.188
72,2017/02/17,19:06:22.360
72,2017/02/17,19:06:27.348
72,2017/02/17,19:06:32.482
74,2017/02/17,19:06:37.515
70,2017/02/30,19:06:42.580"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'C:/Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\DataLog.CSV'
headers = ['Sensor Value','Date','Time']
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), names=headers, parse_dates={'Datetime':['Date','Time']})
print (df)
                  Datetime  Sensor Value
0  2017/02/17 19:06:17.188             2
1  2017/02/17 19:06:22.360            72
2  2017/02/17 19:06:27.348            72
3  2017/02/17 19:06:32.482            72
4  2017/02/17 19:06:37.515            74
5  2017/02/30 19:06:42.580            70

df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
                 Datetime  Sensor Value
0 2017-02-17 19:06:17.188             2
1 2017-02-17 19:06:22.360            72
2 2017-02-17 19:06:27.348            72
3 2017-02-17 19:06:32.482            72
4 2017-02-17 19:06:37.515            74
5                     NaT            70 <- replace 30.2.2017 to NaT (same as NaN for dates)

print (df.dtypes)
Datetime        datetime64[ns]
Sensor Value             int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `names=headers` part as this is confusing `pandas`. `pandas` assumes that the first row is a header rowby default. By specifying the header names, it assumes that the first row must be data and so your error is that the word Date does not match your format (which it doesn't)

EDIT: just change the `read_csv` line to this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\DataLog.CSV')
```

Consequently, you don't have to specify `headers` anymore so you can remove that line.

EDIT2:

The problem is that your date and time fields are deperate. Create a new column, called DateTime, which combines the two and then apply your `striptime` function to that.

Replace the line I told you to delete, the `df['Date'] = df['Date'].map` one with this

```
df['DateTime'] = df['Date'] + " " + df['Time']
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Comment: can you modify my code to do that please? I tried it but still getting same error.

Comment: hello, i just changed the line which you said and it still is giving me error: **ValueError: time data ' 2017/02/17' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'**.

Comment: hello, now that i removed that line, the error now says: **ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 2017/02/17'** I am really stuck at this for the last two days. this is really doing my head in.

Comment: I ran it again and now it is giving me error: **ValueError: time data ' 2017/02/17  19:06:17.188' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'** is it because some kind of whitespaces in the data? or some null data?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while parsing dates in a large csv file. In my case, I had a few bad lines in the csv that were triggering the error, so I simply removed them from the dataframe, to later parse the dates.

If you don't mind to lose this information, you can do something like this:

```
df = df[df['Date'].str.contains(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}')]

timer = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')       

df['Date'] =  df['Date'].apply(timer)
```